# Computer reboots when I plug in a flash drive

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, compaq-desktop-computer

I am working on a Compaq EVO 310 for my uncle.  It is a 2.0GHZ P4 machine.  I have done the following:

Installed a 500GB HDD
fresh install of WinXP Pro 32 bit
installed all drivers from the compaq website for the machine

When I try and plug in my flash drive....does not matter which brand of size to install software the machine will reboot.  It does not matter if I use front or rear panel USB ports.  What the heck is going on?

Comment: Could just be a bad motherboard, I have had several laptops (all Compaq or HP if I remember correctly) which have had the same problem in the past.  What was funny about this problem was if Windows was installed then using the USB port would crash the computer, but if Linux was installed the port just didn't work but the computer didn't crash :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely, the pins inside the USB port on the computer are bent, or the plastic piece in the middle is broken or removed.  What happens is that the usb port is shorting out.  i.e. the +5v line is touching ground or one of the data pins, and the computer shuts itself down to protect itself from damage.  Unfortunately, there is no way to fix this really.  Your best bet is to fill it in with some non-conductive material and never use that port again.

Now, please go back & accept some of your previous questions before you get forever-ignored by people here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's about shorting +5 and GND pin. USB is meant to be shorting proof. It's more likely a broken motherboard or driver problem. Do you have any other USB devices working?